# why is this intel hardware accellerated transcoding in ffmpeg not working?

Tags: ffmpeg

I compiled ffmpeg with intel hardware accelleration, but I cannot transcode the simpsons 720p video from http://www.h264info.com/clips.html with success.

this is the error I get:

> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

and this is the full output from ffmpeg. What could be wrong?

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vcodec h264_qsv out1.yuv
ffmpeg version N-79177-ga677121 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 32.100 / 57. 32.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2007-02-19 05:03:04
  Duration: 00:02:17.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4283 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x544, 4221 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-02-19 05:03:04
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-02-19 05:03:08
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
[h264_qsv @ 0x2f626a0] Error initializing an internal MFX session
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'out1.yuv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 23.98 fps (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-02-19 05:03:04
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.32.100 h264_qsv
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: Does output to MP4 also fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in the v3 release and not yet fixed. For a discussion read the last posts in this thread https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=2562.

Comment: @Jabb that is mentioned in the second last post I linked to, did you not read it?